# Linking Radio Button Results From One Web Form to Another 'Result' Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Essentially, what I am trying to do is allow a user to take a quiz, that consists of five questions.  When the user is done with the quiz they will click the button at the bottom at that form.  I am trying to get the result from a selected Radio Button in a Radio Button List, which I believe I have set up, to a Result Web Form that will say if they got each question right or wrong.  The problem I am running into now is that there are two Web Forms that a user can take a quiz on, and I can't seem to change the 'Result' Web Form's text boxes to public.  Then I could manipulate the text box in the corresponding button method.  So, I added a button in the 'Result' a button that when clicked will take a specific quiz.  I have yet to find a way to set up an IF STATEMENT, so I don't have to specify a quiz. I'll put my code below.

Quiz Chapter 10 Ex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home2
{
    public partial class Chapter10 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public string result;
        public string quiz = "Chapter 10 - Classes and Objects: A Deeper Look";
        protected void chapter10SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ch10RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch10RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch10RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch10RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            } 
            if (ch10RadioButtonList5.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quiz Chapter 8 Ex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home2
{
    public partial class Chapter8 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public string result;
        public string quiz = "Chapter 8 - Arrays; Introduction to Exception Handling";
        protected void chapter10SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ch8RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "true")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch8RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch8RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue == "true")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch8RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue == "true")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
            if (ch8RadioButtonList5.SelectedValue == "false")
            {
                //Result Textbox 1 .text = "Correct"
                result = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                //Result Textbox1 .text = "Incorrect"
                result = "Incorrect";
            }
        }

        protected void chapter8SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs `e)`
        {
            Response.Redirect("Result.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Result Ex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home2
{
    public partial class Result : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        StudentEntities dbcon = new StudentEntities();
        public Chapter10 Chapter10Form;
        public Chapter8 Chapter8Form;
        public int count = 0;
        protected void seeResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            quizTextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.quiz;
            question1TextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.result;
            question2TextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.result;
            question3TextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.result;
            question4TextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.result;
            question5TextBox.Text = Chapter10Form.result;
            if(question1TextBox.Text == "Correct")
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(question2TextBox.Text == "Correct")
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(question3TextBox.Text == "Correct")
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(question4TextBox.Text == "Correct")
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(question5TextBox.Text == "Correct")
            {
                count++;
            }

            totalTextBox.Text = count.ToString();
        }


    }
}
```